# enlarge disk partition El Capitan on vmware

Tags: partitioning, vmware-fusion, osx-el-capitan, disk-utility

I have a version of El Capitan running on my server. However When I first created it I only assigned 40GB to it. Now I want to make it larger so I added 140GB to the disk size. However I don't seem to be able to get the additional 100GB added to the partition no matter what I try.

Also I can't create a partition in the free space that I added. 
I tried booting into recovery mode but it won't let me. Also I don't have a recovery partition. I tried creating one but it didn't work.

Now it will only boot into clover when I press cmd + R. I have absolutely no clue what to do.
I hope someone is able to help me out here because it's getting really frustrating.

Comment: Make the virtual HDD larger using VMWare, then within the Virtual Machine itself, extend the partition.

Comment: That's what I did. The space is added to virtual HDD like I said. However I can't extend the partiton. I can't even create a partition in the free space. When I try to extend my partition it will say finished and it will still be 40GB